# Blank lines in bookdown bibliography

Tags: insert, line, bookdown, bibliography

In using Bookdown I would like to insert a blank line between each entry in the bibliography. My output is rendered in html.

I tried creating css code in the style.css file. I have also carefully read the books and documentation on Bookdown and R Markdown, but did not find any information.